# Notepad++ How do I find and replace part of a directory/file location string?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm trying to replace the middle of a directory string. I know the first two folders will always be the same but the middle is always different. Also the file names will always be different.

For example:

Finding: `c:/Users/owner/someFolder/someOtherFolder/filename.png`
Replacing with: `c:/Users/owner/newFolder/filename.png`

The amount of folders from owner to the file is varies. The file type will always be `png` and `c:/Users/owner/` is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular expresion replace

for example :

replace this :
`c:/Users/owner/someFolder/(.*)/filename.png`     or what ever you want to use instead of (.*)

and replace with what ever you want

Make sure you check the option that says replace using regular expression on the find and replace window otherwise this wont work

Comment: what if filename will always be different?

Comment: Then just use (.*).png for the file name or [a-z0-9]+

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Search what: `(?<=c:/Users/owner/).+(?=/[^/]+\.png)`
Replace with: `newFolder`